# Unable to catch Exception from PrintUI.dll, PrintUIEntry

Tags: batch-file, printing, error-handling, cmd

I"m trying to write a script to automatically install printers using universal drivers. The piece I am unable to determine is which universal driver to use (PS or PCL). So I attempt to handle this in the batch script. I first attempt to install the PCL driver then if that fails I install the PS driver. The problem arises when I try to catch exceptions from the PrintUI.dll.

```
@rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "1.2.3.4 - HP Color LaserJet CP5225n" /f "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpcu130u.inf_amd64_neutral_33833446aad0d0f1\hpcu130.inf" /r "IP_1.2.3.4" /m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"
```

This will fail for the given printer as it needs the PS driver. But if I check `%ERRORLEVEL%` is is always 0. If I attempt the following error handling the outcome is a successful command, but an error is thrown and the printer isn't installed thus NOT successful:

```
@rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "1.2.3.4 - HP Color LaserJet CP5225n" /f "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpcu130u.inf_amd64_neutral_33833446aad0d0f1\hpcu130.inf" /r "IP_1.2.3.4" /m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" 
&& (echo Command Successful) || (echo Command Failed)
```

This test always echoes 'Command Sucessful' eventhough it clearly is not. Does anyone have a decent way of handling errors bc I can't seem to get these to work.

NOTE: I can not use Powershell per our organization's execution policies.

UPDATE:
This is the error I receive.
[image]

Comment: Do you can redirect the output of `rundll32 printui.dll` to a file and does the output is different for successful and unsuccessful installs?

Comment: if redirect stdout or stderr nothing gets written to my text file. An exception window pops up on this command but it's like batch has no idea an error was thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can't solve it with `rundll32` as you can't get the status.

But you can retrieve the information with wmic.

```
wmic PRINTER where name="HP Color LaserJet CP" GET Name
```

With wmic you should be able to detect if the driver is installed or not.

To detect an error you could use FOR/F.
The error output of wmic is redirected with `2>&1` to stdout.

The part `"No instance available."` needs to be modified to your language version of wmic

```
set failure=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`"wmic PRINTER where name='HP Color LaserJet CP' GET Name 2>&1"`) do (
    if "%%L"=="No instance available." set failure=1
)
```

Comment: Is there a way i can store this in a variable and check the value

Comment: Added a sample for this.

Comment: +1 Worked like a charm. If Else statements in batch are something else.